# How should I shuffle a sample into multiple choice options?

Tags: monte-carlo, marketing, conjoint-analysis

We have a database of 10.000 products, each of them having 5 important features such as color and price. One of the features is the popularity of the product.

I am building an app that quickly wants to get the user his feedback regarding some products. With this feedback I can build a classification model, which I then can use to give him recommendations.

This is the idea:

- Take a sample of 64 products out of the 300 most popular products.
- Shuffle these 64 products into 16 questions, so each questions has 4 products. The user goes through the 64 questions and selects each time his favorite out of the 4 products.

The shuffle algorithm should aim to maximize the variability of the features in each question. You don't want 8 questions with only cheap products, and then 8 questions with only expensive products. Ideally, each question contains a cheap and an expensive product. Same applies for the other features, we don't want 8 questions with only blue products, and then 8 questions with only red products. Each question should have a blue and a red product.

**What algorithm can I for this shuffling?**

At the moment I am using some kind of Monte Carlo simulation, but it is not working out that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the (main) objective of your analysis is to measure the influence of the different product features on customers' decisions. This is exactly what conjoint analysis (or choice-based experiment) does. Random sampling from the full list of products (i.e., combinations of product features' values) is not the most common approach (It has been done in the past but is practically expensive because requires a large sample of participants). Instead researchers would use experimental designing techniques to identify the "best" subset of combinations that would allow you to measure the independent effect of each product feature on customers' decisions. The "simplest" is known as orthogonal design. More sophisticated approach would be d-efficient design. Take a look at this very good doc for more info: http://www.choice-metrics.com/documentation.html